# Stop Texture paint from overlapping when strenghts is lower than 1

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, brushes

When I go into texture paint and try to paint with a strenght less than 1 and I "raise" the brush it will overlay the previous stroke, thus darkening it (or strenghtening it).

Edit: I would like to paint over an existing material with multiple image textures, the attached images are just for explanation

I know this is expected behaviour, but I'm trying to give some sort of opacity to my paint so I can see the underlying texture as well. A full strength brush would just overwrite any colour that's under it.

Not raising a brush is not really an option as I need to move the camera and resize whenever I'm paiting on more complex shapes.

This is what happenes:
[image: what happens:]

As you can see in the middle the colours get more "pronounced".

I've also tried adding a 0 alpha image and plugging it and the texture into a colour mix, with the factor coming from the 0 alpha, but that seems to darken the entire texture altogether for some reason.

Not sure if I'm just missing a painfully obvious setting here or something. My shading node knowledge is also pretty basic.

Hope someone can help me here.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: goal]

Comment: You can do this with the Layer Painter 2 add-on by painting on the layer above and then setting that layers Blend mode to, for example Multiply and or change the layers opacity. See screen-shot here for an example: https://gyazo.com/97f70cf295d36e2d1f9548d52807223a .      YouTube Tutorial video of how to get, install and how to use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDt9LFbjJU4      GitHub download page: https://github.com/joshuaKnauber/layer_painter

Comment: @3fingeredfrog This is a great tool if I wanted to make a new texture, in retrospect I really should have explicitly stated that I am trying to paint over an existing material with a complex nodeset. I've tried messing around with it but unfortunately couldn't get it to produce the results im looking for. Thank you either way